# How do I sync a file between OneDrive and local storage?

Tags: sync, onedrive, c++

Our school prescribed syllabus has only Turbo C++. I code on http://codeanywhere.com. It automatically saves my projects on OneDrive. Now, I want Turbo C++ to pick up files directly from OneDrive, instead of where it is mounted. Is it possible to do so? Please tell if you know?

Comment: Just save your project files to the folder set as the drive OneDrive will sync from

Comment: @Ramhound, you mean manually copy pasting the files? If I wanted to do that, I wouldn't have asked here. No form of automation?

Comment: Just point Turbo C++ to the directory with your projects. I thought you wanted Turbo C++ to also save your projects to your OneDrive directory.  This requires you to setup OneDrive syncing on the computer with Turbo C++, I presume you know this, since your asking for Turbo C++ to be aware of your synced OneDrive files.

Comment: You assumed correctly. I want Turbo C++ to save directly in OneDrive folder. can't do it? Please help

Comment: You can indeed do it.  As I said, when prompted to save your project files, just point Turbo C++ to the folder assigned to OneDrive which will automatically sync your local files to to your cloud account.

Comment: Okay, but let me clear a thing, the compiler I use is Borland one, with blue screen. I hope you get now?

Comment: Your not getting me; it's as simply as loading/saving the project from another directory, what is confusing you specifically?

Comment: I completely understand what you are saying. But Borland compiler just sticking to where it is mounted. I cannot specifically move to any folder on the computer. If it is possible, then please tell me!.

Comment: You can't go to File->Save As?

Comment: Nope. I think you haven't used Borland Turbo C++

Comment: i actually have used it, now it was 15 years ago, but I have used it

Comment: I tried changing the default directory to OneDrive. Yes it worked, but whenever I restart the compiler, it again saves to its original one. Though always shows onedrive folder when trying to load a file. But overall useless. :(

Comment: Finally did it. Actually I installed Turbo C++ directly on OneDrive from my PC. I tested the sync by installing it in the same OneDrive folder from Laptop. It worked as magic. My files are now synced awesomely! Now no danger of losing files! :D